# Creating a VPN connection in Windows 7 shows "Unavailable - device missing"

Tags: windows-7, vpn

After I set up a VPN connection, there is an error:

> **Connection failed with error 711**
>
> The operation could not finish because it could not start the Remote Access Connection Manager service in time. Please try the operation again.

Then I go to check the Network Connections, I see the created VPN icon with the following description:

> Unavailable - device missing

Answer (score 7):

This one is working for me.

**First:**

Restart these services manually and make sure they are working:

- Telephony
- Remote Access Connection Manager
- Remote Access Auto Connection Manager

**Second option if first doesnt work:**

- Log on to Windows by Safe mode by an accout with administrative privileges
- Go to your Windows Installed directory (eg . c:\windows\system32)
- Open "LogFiles" folder inside system32
- then the "WMI" Folder
- find folder RTBackup inside it
- What you have to do is delete everything inside the RTBackup Folder
- BUT DO NOT DELETE THE RtBackup Folder!
- After Deleting Everything inside , Just Reboot PC Into Normal Mode

Comment: How to open that folder?  It says "You do not have the permission to view this object's security properties, even as an administrative user"

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/windows-nt-2000-xp/threads/18016/help-needed-how-to-restore-wan-miniport-pptp-device#post1111975) helped me to solve the problem on Windows XP, but didn't helped me to solve it on different machine with Windows 8 64.

I have even tried to use [RAS CMAK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726035%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to create valid connection on a working computer, but when i'm installing the connection on the "broken" system, it says "Unavailable - device missing" (even that it shows VPN icon and not Dial-up icon).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another issue that might have gone wrong:
You might have disabled WAN devices in the device manager.
Open device manager and check if the WAN Miniport devices corresponding to VPN protocols are present.
If you don't see them then they are missing or disabled. 
From the view menu select show hidden devices.
Start the Remote Access Connection Manager service if it is not running and 
meanwhile monitor the WAN Miniport devices in the device manager.
It should effect the WAN Miniport devices if they were missing.
Enable them one by one.

Make sure the three services Telephony,
Remote Access Connection Manager, and
Remote Access Auto Connection Manager 
are properly working.

Now restart your machine.